# Looping through a hash table, finding a value less than a number, and adding that to a new hashtable

Tags: powershell, for-loop, hashtable

I have a server name as a key and its available space as its value like:

```
    $hash= @{}
#in the loop I get the server name and then I get the space as an integer and add it to the table like:
    $hash.add($server,$space)
```

after the loops are complete, I want to go through the list and add the servers with a space less than 80 to a different table using

```
    $badServers = foreach($entry in $serverSpace){
    if($entry.Keys -le 80){
    $badServers.add($entry) 
    }}
```

but my output ends up putting every server into $badServers. Its as if the Values arent actually whats listed. Not sure what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Sure, the last iteration saved in $space is 479, a $space.GetType() gives me Int32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values of your hashtable are of the type `[int]`, for example:

```
PS /> $hash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
SERVER0                        93   
SERVER1                        87   
SERVER2                        84   
SERVER3                        92   
SERVER4                        83   
SERVER5                        58   
SERVER6                        95   
SERVER7                        62   
SERVER8                        81   
SERVER9                        84   
SERVER10                       59
```

You could do something like this:

```
$result = foreach($key in $hash.Keys)
{
    if($hash[$key] -lt 80)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Server = $key
            Space = $hash[$key]
        }
    }
}
```

And looking at `$result` you would get something like this:

```
PS /> $result

Server   Space
------   -----
SERVER5     58
SERVER7     62
SERVER10    59
```

If values were stored as `[string]` ***but holding an actual integer*** you would need to change the condition a bit:

```
if([int]$hash[$key] -lt 80){ ... }
```

---

**Edit Note:**

*Actually, my bad here, PowerShell is smart enough to know how to compare a `string` holding a number with an `integer`. There is no need to cast `[int]`.*

---

And, for example, if the hash was holding values like `123 Gb`, i.e.:

```
PS /> $hash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
SERVER0                        94 Gb
SERVER1                        80 Gb
SERVER2                        82 Gb
SERVER3                        89 Gb
...
...
```

You could do something like:

```
if([regex]::Match($hash[$key],'\d+').Value -lt 80){ ... }
```

Which would yield:

```
PS /> $result

Server   Space
------   -----
SERVER5  52 Gb
SERVER6  53 Gb
SERVER8  69 Gb
SERVER9  72 Gb
SERVER10 65 Gb
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect. Worked like a charm, thank you so much

Comment: @Tabiat1739 I'm happy to help :) and glad it worked out for you. Please, consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it was helpful, it may help others in the future.